# React Native for Windows app

Tags: windows, react-native

I added react native support for windows in my Project. This project is running fine for Android and iOS. Almost, all the code is generic (no Native components are used).

But, when I am running my project in Windows Phone Emulator, it is throwing an error on a red screen -

***Requiring unknown module "ProgressBarAndroid". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the package manager.***

I am not even using the Progress Bar anywhere in my Project.

Can anybody tell what is the issue here ?

Comment: Have you checked all of your dependencies?

Comment: There are no dependencies in React Native code. But, How can I check dependencies for Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved as of this commit:
https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native-windows/commit/2df5cb7ce10fcb26c6b9f7d7fab87e3e821a338a

Which is available in react-native-windows@>=0.29